# Tensorflow how to change hub.Module() to local folder

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

how can I change:

```
BERT_MODEL = "https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_multi_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1"

def create_tokenizer_from_hub_module():
  """Get the vocab file and casing info from the Hub module."""
  with tf.Graph().as_default():
    bert_module = hub.Module(BERT_MODEL)
    tokenization_info = bert_module(signature="tokenization_info", as_dict=True)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      vocab_file, do_lower_case = sess.run([tokenization_info["vocab_file"],
                                            tokenization_info["do_lower_case"]])

  return bert.tokenization.FullTokenizer(
      vocab_file=vocab_file, do_lower_case=do_lower_case)

tokenizer = create_tokenizer_from_hub_module()
```

So that I can load a local BERT model without the `hub.Module()` call as it doesn't work with a local path.

I downloaded a different TF1 pre-trained model from a different website, unzipped it and stored in `/test/module/`.

If I change above `BERT_MODEL = "/test/module"` how would I need to change the rest? I now get string errors as `tokenization_info = bert_module(signature="tokenization_info", as_dict=True)` doesn't work.

Help please I am new to TF - note I need to use TF1, not TF2.

Note: on suggestion below I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-a98e44536f87> in <module>()
      9   return vocab_file, do_lower_case
     10 
---> 11 print(get_bert_tokenizer_info("/tmp/local_copy"))
     12 # Will print: (b'/tmp/local_copy/assets/vocab.txt', False)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/registry.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     43     raise RuntimeError(
     44         "Missing implementation that supports: %s(*%r, **%r)" % (
---> 45             self._name, args, kwargs))
     46 
     47 

RuntimeError: Missing implementation that supports: loader(*('/tmp/local_copy',), **{})
```

Answer (score 0):

`hub.Module` works with local uncompressed paths, so you can change BERT_MODEL to another path and reuse the same code.

Example:

### Create local copy of the module:

```sh
mkdir /tmp/local_copy
wget "https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_multi_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1?tf-hub-format=compressed" -O "module.tar.gz"
tar -C /tmp/local_copy -xzvf module.tar.gz
```

### Use the local copy of the module:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

def get_bert_tokenizer_info(bert_module):
  """Get the vocab file and casing info from the Hub module."""
  with tf.Graph().as_default():
    bert_module = hub.Module(bert_module)
    tokenization_info = bert_module(signature="tokenization_info", as_dict=True)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      vocab_file, do_lower_case = sess.run([tokenization_info["vocab_file"],
                                            tokenization_info["do_lower_case"]])
  return vocab_file, do_lower_case

print(get_bert_tokenizer_info("/tmp/local_copy"))
# Will print: (b'/tmp/local_copy/assets/vocab.txt', False)
```

Comment: Hi thank you! But sorry it does not work - I added the error message I get above;